# Why the default "errorChannel" in spring integration is "PublishSubscribeChannel"?

Tags: spring, error-handling, spring-integration, publish-subscribe

I've found that "The **default** "errorChannel" is a PublishSubscribeChannel" but I can't understand **why**. Can we use a direct channel instead? What is the **downside** of using a direct channel as an inbound channel for errorChannel?

[https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler][1]

Comment: For future readers, official documentation is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/error-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default error channel with whatever channel type you prefer. There is no downside.

Pub/Sub with a logging handler subscribed is simply the default.

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to answer my question. It has really helped me.